# QGIS couldn't load processing plugin - Windows 7

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, loading

I'm having a problem loading QGIS.  Usually it runs fine on my computer.
An error pops up `Can't load processing plugin....`  On QGIS 2.16 I was able to get the full error message.  I've fresh installed 2.18.3 and now get this...

> Plugin processing: The plugin will be disabled because it crashed QGIS during last startup. Please report an issue and re-enable the plugin when the problem has been solved.

Any ideas?

The full error is shown below...

```
Couldn't load plugin processing due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ImportError: cannot import name uic 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 37, in classFactory
    from processing.ProcessingPlugin import ProcessingPlugin
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\ProcessingPlugin.py", line 38, in 
    from processing.gui.ProcessingToolbox import ProcessingToolbox
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 31, in 
    from qgis.PyQt import uic
ImportError: cannot import name uic


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.3 Las Palmas, 77b8c3d 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/msm162/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/msm162/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/msm162/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\msm162\.qgis2\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
.
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall QGIS or tried to install the osgeo4w version? 

Is it possible that you had an 32bits of QGIS earlier and now u went for a 64?